# php Warning & Strict Standards

Tags: php

I am using `$_SESSION[''];` to get values from a user after they have logged in. This data is coming from the `users` table.

I am then trying to

```
`SELECT *` `FROM roster`
```

by doing a query and assigning a var for each value when the users `API=$API`

I can do so by using the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include ('database_connection.php');
    $API        = $_SESSION['API'];

        if ($API !== false) { 
            $roster_query = "SELECT * FROM roster WHERE API='$API'";
            $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbc, $roster_query));

    /* ROSTERS TABLE */
            $StreetName     = $result['streetname'];
            $HouseNum   = $result['housenumber'];
            $City       = $result['city'];
            $State      = $result['state'];     
            $Zipcode        = $result['zipcode'];                               

    /* SESSION */
            $FirstName  = $_SESSION['firstname'];
            $LastName   = $_SESSION['lastname'];
            $Email      = $_SESSION['email'];

    /* this->$vars - Specific for this form */      
            $ExecutionDate  = date("Y:M:D");      
            $DOCSIGNEDBYIP  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        }
```

However, I get the following errors when I do. If I remove the above code no errors, etc.

Now this isnt 'breaking' my code, but I do not want to sweep this under the rug and resolve later.

Can someone identify where I am going wrong ?

> **Warning:** Creating default object from empty value in /home/.../public_html/.../.../.../db.php on line 48

**line 48:** `$return->$i = $row;`

```
if(!$return_array) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql_query)) {
        $return->$i = $row;
        $i++;
    }
```

> **Strict Standards:** Non-static method Access::is_logged() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/.../public_html/.../.../.../APP.php on line 64

**`pinAPP` line 64:** `return Access::is_logged();`

```
public function is_logged()
    {
        return Access::is_logged();
    }
```

is_logged();

```
   <?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'init.php');

    class pinAPP {


        public function is_logged() {
            return Access::is_logged();
        }

    }
```

Access

```
<?php
    class Access {
        private static $auth = false;


        final public function is_logged( $require_admin_access = false ) {
            if ( ! isset($_SESSION[LOGINSESSION]) )
                return false;

            self::$auth = true;

            if ( $require_admin_access ) {
                $u = new User();
                if ( ! $u->is_admin() )
                    new Redirect(DEFAULT_RETURN_URL);
            }

            return self::$auth;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should resolve the line 48 if you do `$return = new stdClass();` before you do the loop. Try that.

Comment: Then under the `Access` class, the `is_logged()` see if it is declared `static function is_logged()` to be used as `Access::is_logged()`.

Comment: Do you mind posting an answer describing a little more detail @Rasclatt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these, see if they work:

```
// Set an empty object for $return first
$return =   new stdClass();

if( ! $return_array ) {
    $i = 0;
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($sql_query) ) {
        $return->$i = $row;
        $i++;
    }
```

I think the other is saying you should have `is_logged()` as a `static` function:

```
class Access
    {
        static function is_logged()
            {
                // code here
            }
    }
```

Comment: My function is_logged() is already within a class that is dependent on my main web application. Any changes to this causes havoc throughout my site. Is there any way I can restructure my query to suite my webapplication? @Rasclatt

Comment: Also this is error from line 64 now - Strict Standards: Non-static method Access::is_logged() should not be called statically in /home/.../public_html/../../../file.php on line 64
`

Comment: The return_array worked. Thank you, however I am getting the error ^^^ above with attempt with the is_logged(); @Rasclatt

Comment: So right now, just the method is causing a problem?

Comment: Ok so the `is_logged()` under the class `Access` can not be `static` or is it static?

Comment: I added my entire file for the class. I stripped everything else out of it.

Comment: But what about the `Access` class? What does that method look like?

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. You have to turn `final public function is_logged( $require_admin_access = false)` to `final public static function is_logged( $require_admin_access = false)`

Comment: Success! Thank you. I appreciate it ;)

Answer (score -1):

1. check `$row` use `!empty($row)` (**just Warning**)
2. can not find `static functon is_logged()`

Comment: Can you be a little more detailed please.